# Does Facebook SDK have a limit for posting to a wall

Tags: facebook

Does Facebook have limits on the number of pages or wall posts an application can post per day?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The choice of SDK has nothing to do with application limits on posts per day.  You could use the PHP SDK, the JavaScript SDK, or the C# SDK you are asking about (or any of many others...Android, IOS, etc.)

Facebook does enforce limits on how many posts per day your app can complete.  It is not a hard and fast number, and varies by app and over time depending on the app's behavior.  If your app produces posts of low quality (spammy), as measured by how many times people comment on, like, or hide your app posts, then Facebook will decrease your daily limit.  These limits are expressed as "buckets" and can be seen on [the Insights page](https://www.facebook.com/insights/) for your app.

You will get an error message back from the Facebook API if you have exceeded the limit.  The error number is 341 and the description is "Feed action request limit reached".  This is enforced on a per-user, per-day basis.

Comment: i couldn't find any of "buckets","diagnostics","allocation" on Insights page do you know where is it located now?

Answer (score 0):

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/247/

It seems there is, though the limit is not static. Check item number 4 on the blog post for more detailed information, but in a nutshell it depends on your application's "ranking" according to an internal algorithm Facebook uses to rank your application.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar experience and came across this post while searching for a reason as to why FB was limiting the number of posts. We were actually doing some testing of sharing news articles from an app authorized with FB and since we were sharing the same link over and over again, it marked them as spammy and decreased our limit to 7!

Here are some guidelines. http://edoceo.com/notabene/facebook-api-oauthexception-341

If you ever happen to be testing, make sure you are not doing the spammy tests because that would decrease the limit on the app.

Comment: thanks ...... so it means facebook keeps an eye on what gets posted and by who........thanks helpful