# Facebook status update code fails to update wall

Tags: facebook

I got the sample code from Facebook to post a message. At first it worked fine. The next day I tried to clean up the code and it stopped working.  I brought back the sample code from Facebook, to take out all my changes, and it still did not work.

I put in print statements to follow the code.

`$user_id` is false, so it displayes a login in.  The login in no longer goes to a login in screen.  It calls my return url, which then sees `$user_id` as being false and diplays the login in again.

I did notice when my call back was being called, I had the following values:

> v?state=452c9492a3d51962909f5e000bcb0965

and code

> code=AQDucDgsdc3lZFVN2MC3Oj2oB0n1LT4FjOrG3MbgwL4uhh--LS-mRdtjU-6oSUZxsR6UhTKuUDVn3hrasJAe5r1I6ksIDJz1nnTo1mjCqEInJKvQ2qK5A-N3_Nt5buGLqsirb8ccg21N4nWVWkk_iRePwX9f68qK1j-2O6E_USpKvRJeNP3bcwLBiTBJpDVu7aA#*=*

I was wondering maybe when I was trying to clean up the code and kept running it, Facebook flagged my app as spamming? I posted 26 posts to my wall - is that too many?  And how would I check if my app has been flagged as a spammy app?

This is the sample code I used

```
<?
// Remember to copy files from the SDK's src/ directory to a
// directory in your application on the server, such as php-sdk/
require_once('facebook.php');

$config = array(
    'appId' => 'myappid',
'secret' => 'mysecret',
);

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<?
if($user_id) {
    print ("tryinmg to do a poast");
    // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
    // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
    try {
        $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
                                array(
                                  'link' => 'www.example.com',
                                  'message' => 'Posting with the PHP SDK!'
                             ));
        echo '<pre>Post ID: ' . $ret_obj['id'] . '</pre>';

    } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
        // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
        // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
        // just ask the user to login again here.
        print ("face book exception log in");
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
                   'scope' => 'publish_stream'
                   )); 
        echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
  }   
  // Give the user a logout link 
  echo '<br /><a href="' . $facebook->getLogoutUrl() . '">logout</a>';
} else {
    print ("no user login in do login");
    // No user, so print a link for the user to login
    // To post to a user's wall, we need publish_stream permission
    // We'll use the current URL as the redirect_uri, so we don't
    // need to specify it here
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => 'publish_stream' ) );
    echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
} 

?>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: No amount of editing will make me able to understand this question.

Comment: -1 completely unintelligible and title sounds like a 2-year-old screaming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naturally, [Facebook has a limit for the number of post per day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880036/does-facebook-sdk-have-a-limit-for-posting-to-a-wall) your app can make to a user wall. And FB have policy for user to report spammy apps as well.

The exact maximum number of posts depends on your application FB ranking. In my experience, 26 posts on a user wall is near the limit for new application.

If that is the case, you should receive the error message from Facebook, which says something like "you have reached limit of posts..."

P/s: It seems you need time to refactoring your question, though. If I have not met this situation before, I won't understand your question.