# What are the different per-day limits for applications to post on a user's Facebook wall?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a facebook canvas application which will post a video plus a description on  1000 user's facebook walls.

What are the different per-day limits Facebook has when posting on users' Facebook walls from an application using the Graph API?

Comment: Above the shift on the left hand side, there is your 'Caps lock' key. hit it.

Comment: It looks like you are asking if there is a way to spam 1000 users... but I'm sure that I am mistaken and there is a perfectly logical and ethical reason behind what i perceive as your intentions.

Comment: Thanx  Merlyn Morgan-Graham ..... for u r link

Comment: Hi Eric , I have already developed this application for considering 100 user's wall...but my client's requirement is to increase this number to 1000 and he asking me what's maximum limit per day for my application to post on user's wall....

Comment: Hi Merlyn Morgan-Graham , I read your reference URL and its very useful for me...my assessment is that facebook may vary maximum number depends upon application ..... But my concern is what 's the initial max number per day????

Answer (score 0):

As Pat James posted in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4881827/91696) to the question [Does Facebook SDK have a limit for posting to a wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880036/does-facebook-sdk-have-a-limit-for-posting-to-a-wall), the limit will vary with your application's behaviour, and you can see your current limit in the [Insights page](https://www.facebook.com/insights/).

Comment: Thanx budy....I got the answer in Insights page...thanks a lot